# Krea Helpdesk - attachments tag not working

Tags: uploads, attachment

Has anyone had trouble using the attachments tag in Krea Helpdesk?  I'm using Helpdesk 1.2.5 with EE 2.9, the form is working fine with the {attachments} tag left out, but as soon as I put it in, I get the following message:

Error

You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing }, or a missing {/if}.

Parser State: Unexpected ‘maxFileSize’ (STRING); expected RD in on line 28.

There are no IF statements on the page and all tags are closed.

Edit: Form Code

```
 {exp:helpdesk:satf}
        <select name="topic">
            <option>Select Topic</option>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
            <option>Option 4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="client_name" name="client_name" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="text" name="client_email" name="client_email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <input type="text" name="client_phone" name="client_phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
        <input type="text" name="summary" name="summary" placeholder="Summary"/>
        <textarea name="issue"></textarea>
        <label>Attachments</label>
        {attachments}
        <input type="submit" type="submit" />
   {/exp:helpdesk:satf}
```

Comment: You might get some help if you post your template code here too or in pastie and link that in your question. This way users can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've edit the question to include the form code.  The only issue is with the {attachments} tag.  If i remove that, it works fine, put it back in and I get the error message.

Comment: It sounds like a bug as per their documentation all you need is that {attachments} tag. Did you try emailing them?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your help.  I have emailed them, but no reply yet, was hoping someone here had come across it.

Comment: Anytime! Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance but they should be able to get you sorted.